# Testing android app using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Firstly I want to make a confession. I've never written a test before. I've been a programmer for more than 10 years, and never once I found the need to write a proper test (or whatever it is called) since mostly I write codes that (I think) can be easily tested manually.

Now I'm writing a pretty complex android app, and this manual testing I'm doing to make sure every functions and classes runs as intended slows me down miserably. So now I'm kinda searching in the dark on how to make my codes test-compatible (is there such a thing?) and where should I start.

I'm using the latest Android Studio (1.2 Beta 3). I found that under 'src' folder, there's an 'androidTest' folder, which (few folders beneath it) contains a file, ApplicationTest.java. Here's the content of ApplicationTest.java

```
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Ok now back to my app. I want to test the class AnalyzerOffline.java (located under main>java>com.code.imin.app) that I've written, because it has pretty complex and large codes going around there. So how should I start? I tried reading http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html , http://rexstjohn.com/unit-testing-with-android-studio/ etc but I still don't know where to start - I feel like I'm missing something here, or maybe somehow my mindset of writing test or the whole idea of it are wrong.

So can please someone show me some light here?

Comment: are you get my answer..

Answer (score 5):

I am using **Monkey tool testing**

**Step 1:**

open the android studio terminal(Tools-> open terminal)

**Step 2:**

In order to use monkey , open up a command prompt and just naviagte to the following directory.

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/home/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/platform-tools
```

**Step 3:**

add this monkey command into terminal and press enter..

see the magic in your emulator.

```
adb shell monkey -p com.example.yourpackage -v 500
```

500- it is the frequency count or the number of events to be sent for testing.

you can change this count..

**More reference,**

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_testing.htm

http://androidtesting.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-testing-with-monkey-tool.html